# How to share AutoKey and TextExpander snippet files : json vs. xml

Tags: python, json, file-conversion, autokey, textexpander

I'm using AutoKey on Ubuntu (12.04) and it works fine. Now I want to use a shared DropBox file, containing all snippets, however this is a TextExpander file because my colleges use MACs and have another app like AutoKey, called TextExpander. 
Their .textexpander file seem to be XML, while my AutoKey uses JSON files.

Can I use a shared .textexpander XML-file with my AutoKey program? 
Is it possible to redirect / convert the .textexpander snippets file (on DropBox) to an autokey.json file, eg. with a Python script and if then how?
Note: I'm not a linux novice, so I can create / adjust some python scripts and access the file system.